# Django - Aggregate into array

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model-view-controller

I use SQLite and have a django model with the below data:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 7 |
| C | 5 |

I would like to use an aggregate my table so that I can get my data in the below format:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | [2,4] |
| C | [7,5] |

How do I do this with Django.

I'm thinking this may be the answer but Django doesn't seem to have ArrayAgg. This looks to be a PostgreSQL function

```
Test_Model.objects.annotate(dname=ArrayAgg('name')).values()
```

Do you know how I can achieve this without using PostgreSQL?
Thank you!

Comment: It has, what database do you use?

Comment: I'm using SQLite

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` , then create the aggregate for any databases:

```py
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [{'Name': key, 'Value': list(item.Value for item in grp)} for key, grp in
    groupby(Test_Model.objects.order_by('Name'), key=lambda x: x.Name)]
```

```py
[{'Name': 'A', 'Value': [1]},
 {'Name': 'B', 'Value': [2, 4]},
 {'Name': 'C', 'Value': [7, 5]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

For *PostgreSQL*, Django has an [**`ArrayAgg`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Test_Model.objects.values('name').annotate(dname=ArrayAgg('value')).order_by('name')
```

Comment: Thank you, William! It's much appreciated. I use SQLite. Do you know if there's a way I can do this without PostGres

Answer (score 1):

First create your own aggregate like this

```
from django.db.models import Aggregate

class GroupConcat(Aggregate):
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s)'

    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, **extra):
        super(GroupConcat, self).__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
            output_field=CharField(),
            **extra)
```

After creating this use below query

```
Test_Model.objects.values('name').annotate(dname=GroupConcat('value')).order_by('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @deepak-tripathi 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74112276/21317829), their solution returns a string. To return a list use SQLite's `JSON_GROUP_ARRAY` aggregation function and Django's `JSONField`:

```python
from django.db.models import JSONField
from django.db.models.aggregates import Aggregate

class JsonGroupArray(Aggregate):
    function = 'JSON_GROUP_ARRAY'
    output_field = JSONField()
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s)'
```

(Don't really need the overridden `__init__()`, unless you want the `DISTINCT` functionality, in which case can also just use `allow_distinct=True`)

And then as @deepak-tripathi says too, to use it:

```python
Test_Model.objects.values('name').annotate(
    dname=JsonGroupArray('value', filter(value__isnull=False)),
).order_by('name')
```

(the `isnull` filter is to avoid `[None]` in aggregated results)